# How to send a private message to user on AWS Chime sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk

I am using AWS Chime JS SDK and would like to send a private message to a user. By message I mean to show a popup modal to an specific user.

I've been going through the documentation, but overall I have not found how to send messages to specific users.

https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-js/modules/apioverview.html#9-send-and-receive-data-messages-optional

Is this possible under Chime?

Answer (score 1):

The data channel within Chime would not allow for this if you wanted secure and private messages.  Optionally, you could filter on the inbound message on each client so that it only popped for the person you wanted.  However, the Chime SDK also has a Messaging SDK that can be used for a case like this:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/business-productivity/build-meeting-features-into-your-amazon-chime-sdk-messaging-application/

You can create private channels.  They are also persistent and can be used for other data sharing use cases.

Comment: Yes, I ended up filtering the inbound message so it only reached the client I wanted.